# Spring Batch what is the scope of slave step

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

In Spring Batch when using a partitioner, What is the scope for slave step? Is there a new bean of slave step created for each execution context?

Comment: The worker step is usually defined as a Spring bean, so it will depend on which scope you've set on that step bean. Can you share your minimal config? Are you using local or remote partitioning?

Comment: I am using local partitioning. I have figured this out. For each partition in a job instance a new scope or slave step bean is being created.

Comment: ok glad you have figured that out.